# Markov process and filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, markov-process

I would like to restate the question.

I'm reading Revuz/Yor's definition of Markov process (P81), they started from transition function, and define the $P_t f(x)$ as usual (let's only consider the time homogenous case here).

A process $X_t$ is called Markov w.r.t $\mathcal F_t$ if

$E(f(X_{t+s})|\mathcal F_t) = P_sf(X_t)\tag{1}$

My previous impression had been that, once a transition function is defined, the induced process $X_t$ should be naturally Markov (w.r.t the natural filtration $\mathcal F^X_t$, of course). It is not clear to me, what is the intuition  of using the more general filtration $\mathcal F_t$ in the definition.

More specifically, consider

$\mathcal F_t = \mathcal F_t^X \vee \mathcal F_t^Y $

where $Y_t$ is another process. If $X_t$ is Markov under $\mathcal F^X_t$, what kind $Y_t$ will make equation(1) hold?

Since equation (1) implies that

$E(f(X_{t+s})|\mathcal F_t) = E(f(X_{t+s})|\mathcal F_t^X)$

which means, knowing the additional information about $Y$ (up to time $t$) will not change how $X$ evolves after $t$. This seems to suggest that $X$ is somehow independent of $Y$, or $Y$ does not provide additional information on how $X$ will evolve. Is there more accurate (and hopefully non-trivial) characterization of such $Y$?

[Below is the old post, will delete later]

Suppose $X_t$ is a Markov process with respect to its natural filtration. Let $Y_t$ be another process. Let $\mathcal F_t=\mathcal F_t^{X,Y}$ be the filtration generated by $X_t,Y_t$ jointly.

Question: under what condition, is $X_t$ Markovian with respect to $\mathcal F_t$?

Intuitively, as long as $\mathcal F_t^Y$ does not have any "future" information about $X_t$, it should be OK. So I guess something like

$E(f(X_{t+s})|\mathcal{F}_t^Y)\in \mathcal F_t^X$

for any positive or bounded measurable $f$.

Thanks

[EDIT] Some interesting special cases: 
(1) $X$ and $Y$ are independent. 
(2) $X$ and $Y$ are jointly Markovian.

I'm not quite sure about (2). To be more specific, if $X$ is Markovian with respect to the natural filtration, and $(X,Y)$ is also Markovian with respect to the natural filtration, prove:

$X_t$ is Markovian with respect to $\mathcal F_t^{X,Y}$

[EDIT] Sorry, keep changing my mind. I guess the above is not true, but need a counter example.

Comment: Come to think of it, $X_t$ may not be   $\mathcal{F}_t^Y)$  measurable, so we have to chang the condition to something like $E(f(X_{t+s})|\mathcal{F}_t)\in \mathcal F_t^X$, which becomes trivial.

Comment: H: First remark if you have a filtration and a process measurable with respect to this filtration there is no reason a priori to suppose that this filtration is the one generated by the process. About the definition, it means that at the process level no other information from the filtration at time t other than the value of the process itself at time t is necessary to get the conditional expectation by any function "f" of the process at t+s. There is nothing more to it and it is fully consistent with the general case of a filtration for which the process is measurable.Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree that a filtration doesn't have to be generated by a process, I used $Y$-generated filtration only to make the question more intuitive.  I just try to understand a Markov process under a general filtration and how it is related to the natural filtration. Put it in another way, let's start from the natural filtration, the question is: how to augment the natural filtration while still keep $X$ Markovian?

Comment: @ Jay H : unless augmentation is done through negligible sets ... this shouldn't affect conditional expectation which are defined only almost surely  ?

Comment: I think arbitrary argumentation will not work in general. There should be some conditions.  Here is a counter example, when  $Y_t=X_{t+1}$, then X is no longer Markovian under $\mathcal F_t^X\vee \mathcal F_t^Y$. I know this is a weird example...

Comment: H : certainly but what has your example got to do with usual augmentation ? Regards

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by usual augmentation. I guess augmentation by completion is the most frequently used one, other than that, I don't know any other  "natural" augmentations. Perhaps you mean adding some information, but the new information is independent of future X?